# Formik / Element Type Is Invalid - got " undefined "

Tags: react-native, formik

I'm trying to use Formik for React Native. I basically copy pasted the plain documentation example which does not work for me, and don't find any other relevant examples to help.
https://formik.org/docs/guides/react-native

I just tried also to use a functional component :

```
 import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import {
  Text, StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';
import { Formik} from "formik";
import { Card, Button, TextInput, View  } from 'react-native-elements';


function AddActivityScreen() {
 return(
   <Formik
     initialValues={{ email: '' }}
     onSubmit={values => console.log(values)}
     >
     {({ handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit, values }) => (
      <View>
        <TextInput
          onChangeText={handleChange('email')}
          onBlur={handleBlur('email')}
          value={values.email}
        />
        <Button onPress={handleSubmit} title="Submit" />
      </View>
    )}
   </Formik>
 )
}

export default AddActivityScreen;
```

I keep having this error :

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `Formik`.
```

I don't understand what the problem is with Formik as I am just executing the code sample  provided in the doc. Please someone help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not related to Formik but the import of your other components

you are importing TextInput and View from react-native-elements which does not exist in that package these are part of react-native itself.

When you do this and try to render, the above error comes up.

Change your imports like below

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import {
  Text, StyleSheet,TextInput, View 
} from 'react-native';
import { Formik} from "formik";
import { Card, Button } from 'react-native-elements';
```

Comment: such a stupid mistake thanks for pointing it out -_- as the error said " formik " i was focused on that

Comment: It happens, whenever you see this error check the imports :)